# no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

We have added the PWA to our Ionic application. ngsw-config.json,and manifest.webmanifest fiels and assets folder are created and index.html file is included with manifest.webmanifest reference and service worker is included in app.module.ts file successfully. But when We run audit the application in browser  we are getting  no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest  error.

Comment: how do you test it? service workers require quite a few things in place (SSL etc)

Comment: maybe the service worker is disabled on dev mode ?